# php не отправляется почта

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail, mail.ru

При отправки почты функцией `mail()` PHP7 выдает ошибку:

> Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your
>   "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in
>   C:\WebData\laba8\sender.php on line 60  Could not send mail! Please
>   check your PHP mail configuration.

И я не понимаю почему он пишет localhost , port = 25 , если в php.ini стоит :

```
[mail function]
sendmail_path = "\"C:/WebSoft/sendmail/sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header = On
```

Остальное в разделе mail_function закоменчено.

В sendmail.ini :

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.mail.ru

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=465

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

default_domain=mail.ru

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging
debug_logfile=debug.log


; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=test.laba8@mail.ru
auth_password=ТУТ МОЙ ПАРОЛЬ

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=pop.mail.ru
pop3_username=test.laba8@mail.ru
pop3_password=ТУТ МОЙ ПАРОЛЬ

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=test.laba8@mail.ru

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```

Стоит win7 , apache 2.4 , php 7

Comment: Почему бы не запустить ваш ненастоящий sendmail в терминале и не попробовать отправить письмо вручную?

Comment: Задание такое, надо через php , а он не видит sendmail пытается через стандартные настройки отправить, хотя я путь прописал

Comment: Ошибки надо любить и не боятся читать.Без них качественный код не выйдет. А вот когда все хорошо то это уже плохо :)

`C:\WebData\laba8\sender.php` В этом файле у вас настройка переопределяется.В ошибке это указано.